# Facebook Application that Searches for nearest Place

Tags: objective-c, facebook, google-maps-api-3, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to create a facebook application that would display a list of the nearest place of interest location?

Much like the current existing Urbanspoon Application (http://www.urbanspoon.com/c/338/Perth-restaurants.html) but on facebook.

Can somebody please point me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get place ID for user's current location:
[SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid=me()](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20current_location%20from%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme%28%29)

Get coordinates for that place ID:
[https://graph.facebook.com/106412259396611](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=106412259396611)

Get nearby places:
[https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=65.5833,22.15&distance=1000](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%2Fsearch%3Ftype%3Dplace%26center%3D65.5833%2C22.15%26distance%3D1000)

You could of course get the latitude and longitude by [other means](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction you're help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a resolved post, but i've also been doing some work on this and thought I'd add my findings / advice...

Using the FQL:

SELECT page_id, name, description, display_subtext FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "52.3", "-1.53333") < 10000 AND checkin_count > 50 AND CONTAINS("coffee") order by checkin_count DESC LIMIT 100

This will get pages containing the word "coffee" in their title, description or meta-data that are within 10k of the specified lat/lon.

```
  "page_id": 163313220350407, 
  "name": "Starbucks At Warwick Services, M40", 
  "display_subtext": "Coffee Shop・Service Station Supply・3,012 were here"
```

I like to set a min check-in count of around 50 to help filter out the ad-hoc places that single users create such as "the coffee machine at jim's house". This helps ensure better quality and relevancy of returned results.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: great advice! I really appreciate it :)